# JClouds: Define firewall rules at Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, jclouds

I am trying to use JClouds to create instances in Google Compute Engine. I am not able to set properly the firewall rules, and the only port that is opened is the 22 (the default one).

I found nothing in the documentation and examples. The following code only opens the port 22.

How can I open some other ports, like 80, 5432, etc ?
Is there any way to open all ports ?

```
    final String POLL_PERIOD_TWENTY_SECONDS = String.valueOf(SECONDS.toMillis(20));

    Properties overrides = new Properties();
    overrides.setProperty(ComputeServiceProperties.POLL_INITIAL_PERIOD, POLL_PERIOD_TWENTY_SECONDS);
    overrides.setProperty(ComputeServiceProperties.POLL_MAX_PERIOD, POLL_PERIOD_TWENTY_SECONDS);

    Iterable<Module> modules = ImmutableSet.<Module> of(new SshjSshClientModule(), new SLF4JLoggingModule());
    //Iterable<Module> modules = ImmutableSet.<Module> of(new SshjSshClientModule());

    ComputeServiceContext context = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("google-compute-engine")
            .credentials("valid email", "valid cert")
            .modules(modules)
            .overrides(overrides)
            .buildView(ComputeServiceContext.class);
    ComputeService computeService = context.getComputeService();

    Template template = computeService.templateBuilder()
            .locationId("asia-east1-a")
            .imageId("https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/ubuntu-1404-trusty-v20150128")
            .hardwareId("https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/MY-PROJECT/zones/asia-east1-a/machineTypes/f1-micro")
            .build();

// Those options are not working as expected
    // List<String> networks = new ArrayList<>();
    // networks.add("default");
    // template.getOptions().as(GoogleComputeEngineTemplateOptions.class).networks(networks);
    // template.getOptions().as(GoogleComputeEngineTemplateOptions.class).inboundPorts(5432,1,2,3);

    Set<? extends NodeMetadata> nodes = computeService.createNodesInGroup("m456", 1, template);

    for (NodeMetadata nodeMetadata : nodes) {
        String publicAddress = nodeMetadata.getPublicAddresses().iterator().next();
        //String privateAddress = nodeMetadata.getPrivateAddresses().iterator().next();
        String username = nodeMetadata.getCredentials().getUser();
        String password = nodeMetadata.getCredentials().getPassword();
        System.out.println(publicAddress);
        System.out.println(username);
        System.out.println(password);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of jclouds are you using? Can you try the [latest 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT](http://jclouds.apache.org/start/install/)?

Comment: @IgnasiBarrera I am currently using 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 1):

Try using the complete URI to "default" network. For eg: "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/xxx-project/global/networks/default"

Comment: If I can assign networks I can potentially assign pre-defined firewall rules. But how can I customize those rules when creating a new instance ?

Answer (score 0):

As per [available providers list](https://jclouds.apache.org/reference/providers/) in JClouds homepage, support for GCE is [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Corg.apache.jclouds.labs). Once you add it to your project, you have the following classes:

- org.jclouds.googlecomputeengine.domain.Firewall.Rule
- org.jclouds.googlecomputeengine.domain.Firewall.Rule.Builder
- org.jclouds.googlecomputeengine.domain.Network
- org.jclouds.googlecomputeengine.domain.Instance.Tags

Although I'm not a Java Developer myself, I bet this is what you are asking for. Using target and instances tags you can restrict the rules only to some instances. If no target targs is used, the ports in the rule will be open for all the instances in the network the rule is applied to. Hope this helps.

Comment: There is a method (that is commented in the code example because it does not work as expected) that is meant to use those classes (".networks" and ".inboundPorts" ). Unfortunately the provided documentation and code examples does not cover port customization. I know that something is wrong, what I do not know yet is what it is.

Comment: Firewall.Rule class has four methods: permitTcpRule(Integer port), permitTcpRule(Integer start, Integer end), permitUdpRule(Integer port) and permitUdpRule(Integer start, Integer end). Once they are applied to the rule before rule creation on GCE side, they will do the work you are looking for. I had a look at the javadoc from JClouds Labs, but I haven't found any inboundPort method.

Answer (score -1):

Google Compute Engine projects have two default firewall rules (on the *default* network) that allow inbound connections (from the internet) on ports 80 and/or 443 to any instance that has the *http-server* and/or *https-server* tag. Said tags can be defined at the moment of VM instantiation, or afterwards.

Comment: This is explaining how Google Compute Engine currently works, but there is nothing that says how can open any port with JClouds. Please note that those rules will be active only if you ever enabled the firewall rules when creating an instance through the web interface. Is not there by default.